# How to format a string to double with respective decimal places and assign to double variable in Java

Tags: java

**Background**
I am getting a scientific value (with exponential). I need to round off this to normal decimal value with two decimal points with double data type

I have done as below

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
x.setByteFor95(Double.valueOf(formatter.format(x.getSrcToDestBytes())));
```

I get the below value while debugging

```
formatter.format(x.getSrcToDest95PercentileBytes())
```

16502416.10

But when converting to double it become scientific value again

```
Double.valueOf(formatter.format(x.getSrcToDest95PercentileBytes()))
```

1.65024161E7

How to get the double type value with two decimal places?
I need to get double with two decimal places at the end

Comment: a primitive (and corresponding wrapper) does NOT have a format - it is just a number - but if you print or convert that number, then it gets a format - in other words, you cannot store a format using a `double` (or `Double`) - you can round a double to a given number of decimal places, but be aware that a floating point is an approximation, not all values can be stored exactly (eventually `BigDecimal` could help)

Comment: You are asking the impossible (and also that which you don’t want in a good program design). You can have any format you want, but only in a `String`.

Comment: (in other words, internally the double `16502416.10` is stored the exact same bits as the double `1.65024161E7`)

Answer (score 1):

Formatting has little to do with the actual value of the number, however in your code where you parse it back to double, it should work **if** the rounded value can be represented exactly by a double. Note that an infinity of numbers cannot be represented accurately by a double, otherwise we would need an infinite amount of memory.

If you want arbitrary accuracy, you should use `BigDecimal` instead. And remember that the way the value is displayed when printing it might still be in scientific notation because this does not alter its value at all, formatting and the value are independent. Using `BigDecimal`, you will be able to control the rounding behavior finely, as you require.